# PyQt: grab mouseMoveEvent inside a Chart

Tags: python, qt, user-interface, pyqt

I have the following PyQt code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtChart import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QValueAxis
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):
    class ChartView(QChartView):
        def __init__(self, chart):
            super().__init__(chart)        

        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            print("ChartView.mouseMoveEvent", event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())

            return QChartView.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    class Chart(QChart):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()

        def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
            print("Chart.mouseMoveEvent", event.pos().x(), event.pos().y())

            return QChart.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)

    def __init__(self, args):
        super().__init__()

        chartView = self.ChartView(self.Chart())
        chartView.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        chartView.setRubberBand(QChartView.HorizontalRubberBand)

        chartView.chart().createDefaultAxes()
        chartView.chart().legend().hide()
        chartView.chart().addAxis(QValueAxis(), QtCore.Qt.AlignBottom)
        chartView.chart().addAxis(QValueAxis(), QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft)

        ls = QLineSeries()
        ls.append(0, 0)
        ls.append(9, 9)
        ls.attachAxis(chartView.chart().axisX())
        ls.attachAxis(chartView.chart().axisY())
        chartView.chart().addSeries(ls)

        self.setCentralWidget(chartView)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    mainWindow = MainWindow(sys.argv)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The problem is that in the code above `mouseMoveEvent` is only emitted for `ChartView`. But I would like to have the `mouseMoveEvent` emitted for `Chart`, rather than for `ChartView`. How could I accomplish this? If it's not possible to have the `mouseMoveEvent` triggered for `Chart`, how could I translate `event.pos()` to `QChart` coordinates inside `ChartView.mouseMoveEvent`?

Comment: to make code more readable put class `Chart` and `ChartView` outside class `MainWindow`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, finally I found a way. I reimplement `mouseMoveEvent` from `ChartView` and have it emit a signal `mouseMoved`:

```
class ChartView(QChartView):
    # ...

    mouseMoved = QtCore.pyqtSignal(QtCore.QPoint)

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.mouseMoved.emit(event.pos())

        return QChartView.mouseMoveEvent(self, event)
```

This signal I connect to a slot of `Chart`:

```
chartView.mouseMoved.connect(chartView.chart().mouseMoved)
```

In the slot I translate the coordinates to the `Chart` coordinate system using `mapFromParent`; I can even map it into the coordinate system of the series using `mapToValue`:

```
class Chart(QChart):
    # ...

    def mouseMoved(self, pos):
        print("Chart.mouseMoved parent coord domain: ", pos)
        print("Chart.mouseMoved own coord domain:", self.mapFromParent(pos))
        print("chart.mouseMoved line series coord domain:", self.mapToValue(self.mapFromParent(pos), self.series()[0]))
```